# Sonkeigo forms of できる and なかったら

Tags: usage, sonkeigo

「できる」の尊敬語はありますか。「おできになる」は使われていますか。（見たことはありませんが．．．）

また、「あったら」は「おありでしたら」になると思いますが、「なかったら」はどうなりますか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「おできになる」は普通に使います。「勉強ができる人 → 勉強がおできになる方」というふうに。

仰るとおり、「あったら」を尊敬語にすると「おありなら」、さらに丁寧語化して「おありでしたら」になります。

「なかったら」の尊敬語はありません。

Answer (score 2):

「できる」なら「可能になる」はいかがでしょうか。「ある」なら「ございます」、「なかったら」なら「ございませんでしたら」のほうが普通なのでは、と思われますが。

Comment: 「ございます」は尊敬語ではなくて丁寧語だという意見もあります。相手が主語でも自分が主語でも使え、聞き手に尊敬を表す表現とのこと。相手に「です・ます」を使わない場合、目上の人の話をする時でも「ございます」は使わないので、やはり丁寧語ではないでしょうか。